# Reboot stuck on "Started advanced key-value store"

Tags: boot

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I rebooted the system when there was an unattended update running.  It  gives the following error messages

```
[FAILED] failed to listen to udev Control Socket
[FAILED] failed to listen to udev kernel Socket
```

then keeps getting stuck on
Started advanced key-value store.temd-network.ce....d before the ppp link was shut down ...

Sometimes it gets stuck on

```
 Started Dispatcher daemon for system-network.ce....ystem changes.pp link was shut down...
```

instead